# What's a "completion of comprise"?

Tags: legalese

I scanned this because I don't know how to format 2 columns here, or add color. I [Googled "completion of comprise"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22completion+of+comprise%22&source=lmns&bih=510&biw=1088&client=firefox-b-d&hl=en-US&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi5iIubhZHvAhVDa6wKHRNEDdQQ_AUoAHoECAEQAA) and found just 4 results, and 2 were from this book.

[image]

Stacie Strong. [BA English literature (UC Davis 1986), MPW (USC 1990), JD (Duke 1994), PhD Law (Cambridge 2002), DPhil (Oxford 2003)](https://www.linkedin.com/in/s-i-strong-50b82832/). *How to Write Law Essays & Exams* 5 Ed 2018. 221.

Comment: The example you pasted suggests that this is an archaic legal term, you might get a better response on the Law SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Comprise* is a verb, according to dictionaries. Even legal dictionaries seem to give it as a verb:

> = The whole comprises the parts; the parts compose the whole.
>
> [Law Insider](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/comprise)

In this case *comprise* has been used (quite arbitrarily, and without definition or justification) as a noun that embraces **any or all of the parts that comprise the legal contract**.

The phrases “entire completion” and “entire completion” emphasise that payment is only required on completion of **all parts**. The agreement is that you only get paid if you do all the job.

Reference to *substantial performance* as a *mitigation* of the *all parts* condition admits the possibility of staged payments in relation to work done. The agreement is that you get paid parts of the total sum for parts of the job.

The prose about the garage merely illustrates these two approaches to the contract. Why such simple concepts have to be dressed up with such obscurity, distortion of usual English usage and solecism (build = built?) is beyond this simple correspondent.

Comment: I ask in comment, it being mere supposition or opinion: in an account of “How to write ...”, was this example actually a counter-example, showing how clear law should *not* be written?

Answer (score 0):

Once again, no expert here. Law is not my field. My best guess on this one is that the white column simply says that when you state in a signed contract that you are going to build a house for your client, you have to do exactly as you stated and complete your contract by building that house. For finishing half way is breach of contract.